# Code Map does not appear in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-map

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 but I can't find Code Map there.
Can anyone show me where to find it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx

Comment: I have already read it but icon of Code Map isn't in my vs

Comment: what SKU of VS are you using?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas visual studio 2013 professional

Answer (score 9):

You cannot see the Code Map as it is only exists in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version and not in your version which is professional.